# How to add decimal point from a string into a numerical value

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, decimal

I want to be able to have a decimal point when I enter my numbers through this code and what the code does is that is it just displays numbers when you enter them like if i clicked 5 twice it would be 55 but what if I wanted 5.5, how would I do that?

```
var number = '';
var number1 = '';
var number2 = '';
function selectNum(num) 
{
    number += num;
    number = parseInt(number);
    document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = number;
}


<button onclick = "selectNum('7')">7</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('8')">8</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('9')">9</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('4')">4</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('5')">5</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('6')">6</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('1')">1</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('2')">2</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('3')">3</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('0')">0</button>
<button onclick = "selectNum('.')">.</button>
```

Comment: 55 is a bad example really.. What if you press 5 and then 3, what is the expected output?

Comment: @ScottHunter parsing 55 using parseInt or parseFloat doesn't make any difference in current case, since OP is missing logic in making the number decimal.

Comment: If you want clicking `5` twice to mean *5.5*, what is the point of the `.` button?

Comment: no i mean i when i click 5 twice i get 55, but i want it to be 5.5 when i click the . button @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're calling `parseFloat` on a string before it has a chance to display. And according to the rules of `parseFloat` the argument `1.` is parsed to `1`, and the decimal place is removed.

To fix this I would try something like this:

```js
  var number = '';
  var number1 = '';
  var number2 = '';
  function selectNum(num)
  {
   number += num;
   document.getElementById("outputbox").innerHTML = number;
   if (!number.slice(-1) == '.') {
    number = parseFloat(number);
   }
  }
```

```html
  <button onclick = "selectNum('7')">7</button>
  <button onclick = "selectNum('8')">8</button>
  <button onclick = "selectNum('9')">9</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick = "selectNum('4')">4</button>
  <button onclick = "selectNum('5')">5</button>
  <button onclick = "selectNum('6')">6</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick = "selectNum('1')">1</button>
  <button onclick = "selectNum('2')">2</button>
  <button onclick = "selectNum('3')">3</button>
  <br />
  <button onclick = "selectNum('0')">0</button>
  <button onclick = "selectNum('.')">.</button>
  <div id="outputbox"></div>
```

The only issue left is now multiple decimals are allowed within the string.